# Antialiasing in Plot3D doesn't work well

Tags: plotting, antialiasing

My code is very simple:

```
Style[Plot3D[Cos[x + 0*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -2, 42}, Mesh -> None], 
  Antialiasing -> True]
```

There seems some ripple on the top of the figure and I doubt whether it is mathematica's 3D rendering bug.

PS: I'm using mathematica 11.0 on Windows 7 64-bit and I've already turned antialiasing option on.

[image]

Comment: The `Antialiasing` option isn't doing anything here, compare the result to what you get without the `Style` wrapper.  To get rid of the ripples, use `Plot3D[Cos[x + 0*y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -2, 42}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: Thank you! It works with the PlotPoints option added.

Comment: Instead of PlotPoints, you can also use MaxRecursion -> 5.  Use Mesh -> All to see what it does.